# NativeScript global event handler in an XML declaration?

Tags: javascript, android, xml, nativescript

So I am trying to figure out if this is possible with NativeScript.

So I understand that to be able to add an event handler in an XML declaration, you must have a the function defined in the javascript file like this (**main-page.js**):

```
exports.testAlert = function(){
    alert('test alert');
}
```

Which I can then use in the XML file (**main-page.xml**):

```
<Button tap="testAlert" text="testAlert" height="50px" style="font-size:20px;" />
```

The problem is that I cannot use the "testAlert" function globally in another page (**inside-page.xml**).

Initially I tried working with the global object and declaring the function I want to be global in the **app.js** file like this:

```
global.testAlert = function(){
    alert('test alert');
}
```

I first thought that I could access the function in the XML like before:

```
<Button tap="testAlert" text="testAlert" height="50px" style="font-size:20px;" />
```

Which did not work, so I thought maybe like this (**global.testAlert**):

```
<Button tap="global.testAlert" text="testAlert" height="50px" style="font-size:20px;" />
```

But in order to have the same function I need to create it again in the **inside-page.js** file or at least link the global function to a local one like so:

```
exports.testAlert = global.testAlert;
```

Is there away to create event handlers within a single JS file that can be used in any of the XML pages? Possibly kept in the **app.js** file?

Or if all the global functions were in its own file like **global-functions.js** then included where I need it?

In addition to this, I am aware that you can also add event handlers within the JS file. Now I do not mind this approach, if it would work globally?

So ultimately I want to be able to create global functions and variables which I can then use anywhere in my app.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

**My current solution:**

So I found a work around for now, its not ideal, but it works for me.

I first created an object (global.toolbox) in **app.js** to keep all my functions and variables:

```
// This is just a technique I stumbled across to avoid UNDEFINED errors
// Should be placed at the top of each JS file
global.toolbox = global.toolbox || {};
```

I define the global objects as normal:

```
global.toolbox = global.toolbox || {};
global.toolbox.testFunction = function(){
    alert('test alert');
}
```

Then to access these global functions in other pages, I do need to add a little snippet to "export" the global functions to be accessible by the XML file, this will be in **main-page.js** for example:

```
global.toolbox = global.toolbox || {};
for (var k in global.toolbox){
    if (global.toolbox.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
         exports[k] = global.toolbox[k];
    }
}
```

I put that at the top of each JS file for each XML file.

Now I am able to access the global functions in the XML files:

```
<Button tap="testFunction" text="testFunction" height="50px" style="font-size:20px;" />
```

I would still like to see if there is a way to have to avoid adding the snippet to each JS file and make truly global functions for XML declarations.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I found some workaround to do what you need. See here:
https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/2860

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to accomplish something similar, and found an inobvious, albeit effective and simpler, solution.

Step 1:  Add the functions you want, into the application resources.

e.g. in app-root.js:

```
const application = require("application");
...
Object.assign(application.getResources(), {
    testAlert(message) {
        return function(args) {
            dialogs.alert(message);
        }
    },
    testAlertWithPredefinedMessage() {
        return function(args) {
            dialogs.alert('This alert message was predefined');
        }
    },
    whateverOtherGloballyAvailableHandlerYouWant(whatever, args, you, want) {
        return function(args) {
            // Here, put whatever you want this event handler to do.
            // Note the one limitation:  None of the arguments can be function declarations, nor lambdas.  However, strings, numbers, booleans, etc, all work.
        }
    }
};
```

Step 2:  In the XML, use binding syntax AND parentheses:

```
<Button text="Tap me!" onTap="{{ testAlert('Thank you for tapping!') }}" />
<Button text="Note that the parentheses are still required, even if there are no arguments to pass in" onTap="{{ testAlertWithPredefinedMessage() }}" />
```

Inobvious, but simple, and highly effective.

---

Bonus:  Suppose you want to do something more complex, and still do as much of it as possible in the XML.  e.g. suppose you want to define a function or lambda that you pass as an argument to some other function, and you want to do that in the XML.

**Warning:**  If you do not want to use eval, or feel that eval is always evil, please stop reading, block your ears, and sing "la la la" while I quickly explain a few tricks.

Bonus step 1:  Make a "truly evil" eval, that always runs in the very most global scope.

```
const geval = eval; // "geval" stands for "global eval", but if you want, you could call it "gevil" or such like instead.
```

Bonus step 2:  Add these global event handlers to the application resources:

```
Object.assign(application.getResources(), {
    geval(expression) {
        return function(args) {
            geval(expression);
        }
    },
    gevalProp(propertyName) { // The reason for this will be more evident shortly.
        return function(args) {
            geval(args.object[propertyName]);
        }
    }
};
```

Bonus step 3:  Now put arbitrary code directly in the XML, as a string argument to geval:

```
<Button text="Tap me!" onTap="{{ geval('dialogs.alert(`Thank you geval!`)') }}" />
```

However, if you're paying close attention, you'll notice that the only javascript string delimiter available for unescaped use inside that code expression, is the backtick.  Depending on what you're trying to accomplish, that might be sufficient, or it might be frustrating, or it might be unworkably restrictive.

Enter (drumroll) gevalProp.  It allows you to store the expression-to-evaluate in a separate property, which allows you to free up one of the two other available string delimiters for use in your expression to evaluate.  e.g.

```
<Button text="Tap me!" onTap="{{ gevalProp('onTapExpr') }}" onTapExpr="dialogs.alert('Thank you gevalProp!')" />
```

Of course, you might ideologically or stylistically dislike this, and that's fine - ignore this "bonus" section in that case - but for those who wish to push the boundaries and know what's possible, this is possible.